# Finding correct loop

Tags: matlab, loops, vectorization, cell-array

I have a dataset consisting of 80k rows. It's stored in a cell.
In the third column the values should go such as -3 in the first row, -2 in the second -1 in the third and so on all through the whole dataset.
As :

```
-3
-2
-1
-3
-2
-1
...
```

Now I want to check whether or not this number sequence is actually being followed throughout the whole dataset. I know for a fact it isn't and therefore I want to make some kind of loop that automatically removes the whole rows of data that doesn't follow the -3, -2, -1 steps.

My initial thought was to use `diff` command to change index, but can't seem to get it right.

Second was to create a loop that would remove data every time it didn't follow the specific number sequence.

```
for i = 1:length(Dataset)
    if Dataset{272,1}(i,3) == -3
        continue
    else
        eraseidx = Dataset{272,1}(i,3)
        if Dataset{272,1}(i+1,3) == -2
            continue
        else
            eraseidx = Dataset{272,1}(i,3)
            if Dataset{272,1}(i+2,3) == -1
                continue
            else
                eraseidx = Dataset{272,1}(i,3)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

(Reason for choosing `Dataset{272,1}` is that I know there is a fault).

Anyone have a method for solving this?

Answer (score 0):

Your loop has one main problem: you nest all conditions under each other, so you check for `i+1` and `i+2` only if the first condition where `false`, but then you check again for them as you come to the next iteration of the loop. If `Dataset{272,1}(i+1,3) == -2`, then you already know that on the next iteration (when you compare `Dataset{272,1}(i,3)` to `-3`) it will return `false`, but is it `false` or `true`?! according to your loop it depends on *when* you ask this...

Here are two options to correct this, still using a loop. The first way it to loop on all `k` (I replace `i` with `k` to not override the imaginary unit in MATLAB), but compare `Dataset{272,1}(i+1,3)` to a different number:

```
c = [-1 -3 -2];
for k = 1:length(Dataset)
    if Dataset{272,1}(k,3) ~= c(mod(k,3)+1);
        eraseidx = Dataset{272,1}(k,3);
    end
end
```

Another option is to compare the data in triplets:

```
for k = 1:3:length(Dataset)
    if Dataset{272,1}(k,3) ~= -3
        eraseidx = Dataset{272,1}(k,3);
    end
    if Dataset{272,1}(k+1,3) ~= -2
        eraseidx = Dataset{272,1}(k+1,3);
    end
    if Dataset{272,1}(k+2,3) ~= -1
        eraseidx = Dataset{272,1}(k+2,3);
    end
end
```

Right now you only save the problematic records to `eraseidx`, but you overwrite it each time any of the conditions is fulfilled, so you need to also index `eraseidx`:

```
eraseidx = zeros(length(Dataset),1);
c = [-1 -3 -2];
for k = 1:length(Dataset)
    if Dataset{272,1}(k,3) ~= c(mod(k,3)+1);
        eraseidx(k) = Dataset{272,1}(k,3);
    end
end
```

However, if you only want to delete those records you can save the `k` alone as logical indexing, and not all the record. Also, it seems to me that your loop should run on `1:length(Dataset{272,1})` so:

```
eraseidx = false(length(Dataset{272,1}),1);
c = [-1 -3 -2];
for k = 1:length(Dataset{272,1})
    eraseidx(k) = Dataset{272,1}(k,3) ~= c(mod(k,3)+1);
end
```

And this could be easily vectorised to:

```
c = [-1 -3 -2];
k = 1:length(Dataset{272,1});
eraseidx = Dataset{272,1}(k,3) ~= c(mod(k,3)+1).';
```

So now `eraseidx` will be a logical vector, so that `Dataset{272,1}(eraseidx,:)` will be all the records from `Dataset{272,1}` to be deleted. **Edit:** To delete them you just write: `Dataset{272,1}(eraseidx,:) = []`.

---

### Vectorize on all `Dataset`

In case all the data in all cells has the same size and shape, you can use `cell2mat` to convert it to a ND-array, and then perform a vectorized operation on all data at once:

```
data = reshape(cell2mat(Dataset.'),[],3,numel(Dataset)); % convert to 3D array
c = [-1 -3 -2];
k = 1:size(data,1);
correct = c(mod(k,3)+1).'; % the correct values to compare 
eraseidx = squeeze(bsxfun(@ne,data(:,3,:),correct));
```

Now each column in `eraseidx` corresponds to a third column in `Dataset`, so the result for `Dataset(k,1)` is given in `eraseidx(:,1)`.
To delete all `true` records in `eraseidx` you can use a simple loop:

```
for k = 1:numel(Dataset)
    Dataset{k}(eraseidx(:,k),:) = [];
end
```

Notice that you cannot delete the records directly from `data` because arrays cannot have different number of rows in each element of the third dimension.

---

**If `Dataset` has to be a cell-array...**

If you're using cells to keep the data in `Dataset` because it is not in the same size and shape, you can adjust the above loop for all the process:

```
c = [-1 -3 -2];
for k = 1:numel(Dataset)
    eraseidx = Dataset{k,1}(:,3) ~= c(mod(1:length(Dataset{k,1}),3)+1).';
    Dataset{k,1}(eraseidx,:) = [];
end
```

Or you can use `cellfun` (which is basically a compact loop):

```
c = [-1 -3 -2];
delfun = @(M) M(M(:,3)==c(mod(1:length(M),3)+1).',:);
Dataset_fixed = cellfun(delfun,Dataset,'UniformOutput',false);
```

`delfun` is an anonymous function that retrieve only the wanted records from each cell in `Dataset`. Now `Dataset_fixed` is `Dataset` without the deleted rows.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

Can I vectorise it when it should run through the whole dataset and not only `Dataset{272,1}` ?
Furthermore when I run `Dataset{272,1}(eraseidx,3)`  it doesn't remove the "corrupted" numbers but just returns the two numbers (in this case -2 and -1) where the loop inside the dataset went wrong

Comment: @user3161344 See my edit for vectorizing on all `Dataset`, and deleting the records.

Comment: @user3161344 please let me know if this answers your question, and if so consider [upvote/accepting](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it